# Saving Polymorphic model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic model; result, with `belongs_to result_table, polymorphic: true` which i'm using with two other models; team and sport,  through a one to one relationship and its working. Due to the one to one relationship, i have a callback function,`after_create :build_result_table` which i use in setting and saving the `result_table_id` and `result_table_type` in the result table in the database. The issue I have is the input saved in `result_table_type`, its VARCHAR, but it seems to be saving the input as an integer

```
def build_result_table
  Result.create(result_table_id: self.id, result_table_type: self)
end
```

I think the issue is probably with `result_table_type: self`, but i tried `result_table_type: self.class.name` to save the name of the class but it threw an error. Any advice on saving a unique value in the `result_table_type` column..

---

EDIT

I'm adding the models involved, though i have done the saving manually as said by @Mohammad in the comments, but will also be grateful, if i can be shown how i can ask rails to save the values automatically.

APP/MODEL/SPORT.RB

```
class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :sport_name, :sport_id, :result_attributes, :result_table_id
 has_one :result, as: :result_table

 after_create :build_result_table
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :result

 def build_result_table
    Result.create(result_table_id: self.id, result_table_type: self.class.name)
 end

end
```

APP/MODEL/TEAM.RB

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :result, as: :result_table

 attr_accessible :teamname, :color, :result_attributes

 after_create :build_result_table

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :result

 def build_result_table
   Result.create(result_table_id: self.id, result_table_type: self.class.name)
 end

end
```

APP/MODEL/RESULT.RB

```
 class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sport_id,:team_id, :result_table_id, :result_table_type
  belongs_to :result_table, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: In polymorphic relations, the type field is the class name of the class, it's auto filled by rails, but if you want to do it manually, then `self.class.name` would be the right answer, the even better way would be letting rails do the whole thing, like saying something like `result.result_table = self` and rails will handle the rest

Comment: Please post the full models. There should be no need to set the type and id yourself if you got the assosiations right. By the way, the assosiation name "result_table" is misleading. I think you mean "resultable", the english term for something you can do with the type. Like a Post is commentable, a Book is readable and a Beer is drinkable

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, thanks for your explanation but the line  `result.result_table = self` throws the error `undefined method `result_table=' for #<Class:0x50865d8>` . Also @Sander Garretsen, thanks.

Comment: i knew it would, i was just explaining the concept, just like @SanderGarretsen said, we need to see you models to understand what exactly is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Either one of these
Result.create(result_table: self)
Result.create(result_table_id: self.id, result_table_type: self.class.to_s)
```

Comment: thanks. `self.class.to_s` can be easily over written but tself.class.name` did work after restarting the server.